# Add new minor nodes to private Ethereum network set up using AWS Blockchain Template

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, blockchain, ethereum

I've a private Ethereum Blockchain set up on AWS using the [AWS Blockchain Templates](https://aws.amazon.com/blockchain/templates/getting-started/). I can add minor nodes during the stack deployment by listing the wallet address in the corresponding field. I was wondering if there is a way I can add new minor nodes to the network once the stack is completely deployed and the network is up and running. I can connect new people to the network using the RPC endpoint but how do I add new minor nodes?
Any input is appreciated.